# splunk workflow actions not working

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-formula, splunk-calculation, splunk-sdk

I am trying to create an incident using splunk POST workflow action. From event when i try to trigger the workflow action a new window is opened and the query string is getting appended to URL but the values are not filled in the fields.

how to resolve this issue?

Comment: do we have any clear tutorial on creating a defect (eg. using jira) with Workflow action?

Comment: And how will we know if the URL im hitting with POST workflow action accepts query param?

Comment: Any answers for this question